# React map not rendering array but console.logs

Tags: reactjs

Inside this map no rendering happens but console.log prints the array elements.

```
{(repos.length > 0) ? repos.flatMap((v, i) => {
                                
if (e1 === (v[2]) && v[1].length>0) {
  v[1].map((e)=>{
    console.log(e)
    <div></div>//no view rendering..
```

prints these on console

```
dashboard.tsx?91c8:646 (2) ["0x78Ba3149274C76921249200c090cCFCF3Cc86e85", "0"]
dashboard.tsx?91c8:646 (2) ["0x4DD660E14E9d90eE5180b49c5833D4d0f5295daa", "0"]
```

this is also not rendering

```
v[1].map((e)=>("assasasa"))
```

check this out

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-architecture-ljo89?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Include more details. I think you are not returning the result inside the map.

Comment: ([1,2,3]).map((e)=>{return ("assasasa")} this is also not rendering

Comment: v[1].length =2 but not rendering with map console.log prints data

Comment: Update these things in the question itself

Comment: Still not getting the issue. Can you add a codesandbox.

Comment: yes added one .

Comment: pls check the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning the result inside the map

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      {box.map((e) => {
        return box.map((e) => {
          return "aassssaa";
        });
        //return ("aaaa")
      })}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

code - https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-frog-n664n?file=/src/App.js:143-415

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the item you want to render.

For example:

````js
{array.map( (element) => {
    return <div>{element}</div>
})

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you are using `{}` inside `.map()` method, instead you should use `()` to render JSX.

```
{(repos.length > 0) ? repos.flatMap((v, i) => {
                                
if (e1 === (v[2]) && v[1].length>0) {

  v[1].map((e)=>
(
    {console.log(e)}
    <div>
     e
    </div>

)
}})}
```

Comment: still not rendering

Comment: Can you share `repos` ?
I guess `e` itself is  an array or object and hence the problem.